# History button in sidebar freezes/crashes iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

In the sidebar in the iOS app, the "history" button keeps freezing the app for about thirty seconds, after which it either finally loads or the app crashes. I have been unable to find a pattern for when it does which.

I have tried closing the app from multitasking during that window, and the app takes a good 10-15 seconds to open afterwards.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: @Cal Absolutelt a dupe. Thanks for pointing that out.